# Share a list of locks across processes in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, locking, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a project that shares `chrome browsers` started using `selenium package` across multiple processes. Since these browsers (stored as a list object) are shared across processes using a `Manager.list()`, I also want to share a corresponding list of `Manager.Lock()` across the processes so that processes obtain a `lock` on a browser before accessing urls via it. However I am getting error regarding serialization of `lock` as follows in the sample code:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Manager
>>> manager = Manager()
>>> lock_list = manager.list()
>>> lock_list.append(manager.Lock())
>>> print type(lock_list[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in __getitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 774, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unserializable message: ('#RETURN', <thread.lock object at 0x7fa2115452b0>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>>
```

If someone can help me get around this that would be really great. Thanks.